Powershell - iterate through CSV file
i'm sruggeling with some script that checks NW connectivity between hosts basicaly i have CSV with source IP and port which looks like this

the problem is when i run this script it checks me every ip with every port and i need it to check onlu port that is next to it i .e for 8.8.8.8 only port 53 and for 1.1.1.1 only 443
below is my code
$dest = Import-Csv "C:\temp\dest.csv"
#$dest | ft
$source = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem).name
Foreach ($d in $dest.SourceIP){
    Foreach ($P in $dest.Port){
        try{ 
            $temp = new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
            $temp.Connect("$d", $P)
                if ($temp.Connected -eq $true){
                    Write-Host $P -ForegroundColor Green " => port is open from" $source "to" $d
                }
            }
        catch {$theError =$_
                if($theError.Exception -like "*A connection attempt failed*"){
                    Write-Host $P -ForegroundColor Red "=> NO TRAFFIC between" $source "and" $d
                }
                elseif($theError.Exception -like "*No connection could be made*"){
                    Write-Host $P -ForegroundColor Red "=> port is closed from" $source "to" $d
                }
              }
     }
}

I know that nested loop is the problem here but i ran oout of ideas how to change it to make it work properly

Loop through each row of has table using : Foreach ($row in $dest){ }  The check $row.SourceIP and $row.Port.

You're accidentally using something called "Member-Access Enumeration"  - $dest.SourceIP is retrieving an array that contains the SourceIP values from all rows, and $dest.Port is doing the same for the Port property. As a result, your nested foreach loops are iterating over every port for every SourceIP which explains the behaviour you're seeing. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.4 for more details about this feature (which you don't actually want to use here!)

Only an idea... you might gain some speed by groupimg.  Something like Group-object -property Port

Get-WmiObject is obsolete. Use Get-CimInstance works pretty much the same.
And why the nested loop in first place? You can access the properties!
$source = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Computersystem).Name

Foreach ($Address in $dest) {
    $PortString = '{0,-5} => ' -f $Address.Port

    try { 
        if ([System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new($Address.SourceIP, $Address.Port).Connected) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $PortString 'port is open from' $source 'to' $Address.SourceIp
        }
    }
    catch [System.Net.Sockets.SocketException] {
        switch ($_.Exception.ErrorCode) {
            10060 { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $PortString 'NO TRAFFIC between' $source 'and' $Address.SourceIp }
            10061 { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $PortString 'port is closed from' $source 'to' $Address.SourceIp }
        }
    }
    catch {
        # generic error management 
    }
}

and if you are using Powershell Core/7.x and you have many elements to check, you can use Foreach-Object -Parallel. See:
$source = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Computersystem).Name

Import-Csv -Path $CsvPath | ForEach-Object -Parallel {

    # technically superfluous, but helps readibility.   
    $Address = $_

    # necessary to access the out-of-scope $source varible.   
    # the local name could by anything, but I kept the same name for clarity.   
    $source = $using:source

    $PortString = '{0,-5} => ' -f $Address.Port

    try { 
        if ([System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new($Address.SourceIP, $Address.Port).Connected) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $PortString 'port is open from' $source 'to' $Address.SourceIp
        }
    }
    catch [System.Net.Sockets.SocketException] {
        switch ($_.Exception.ErrorCode) {
            10060 { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $PortString 'NO TRAFFIC between' $source 'and' $Address.SourceIp }
            10061 { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $PortString 'port is closed from' $source 'to' $Address.SourceIp }
        }
    }
    catch {
        # generic error management 
    }
}


Very Nice. You might wanna add a separate catch [System.Net.Sockets.SocketException] {...} block and test the $_.Exception.ErrorCode value (to avoid comparing against localized error message) - the "connection attempt failed" error will have code 10060, "No connection could be made" is 10061

@MathiasR.Jessen thanks for the edit on my post by the way. And yeah, there are multiple ways to improve the script. I only focused with the main issue OP did rise, the double-loop. I've edited my solution with your suggestions and a couple other improvements(I hope)

Thank You very much, it works. i used nested loops because previously i've checked source ip or a bunch ow IP's directly provided to script  and multiple ports bot those ports were the same for all ip's to check. Anyway i've noticed that it's noo very efficient way to do this co i wanted to change it to csv files and even if i will have to duplicate lines with IP to check some more ports for the same address it will be still better way to do it. Thank You once again

if you use Powershell Core/7.x and have many items to check, I added to my solution a variant taking advantage of Foreach-Object -Parallel which would let you check multiple IPs at the same time, making things much faster
